# CUDA вызов kernel в цикле

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel

Стоит задача, нужно вызывать ядро в цикле, но после первой итерации скалярное произведение начинает считать неправильно.
Ядро:

```
__global__ void scaMult_g(float* a, float* b, float* c, float* sum, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    if (tid > n - 1) return;

    c[tid] = a[tid] * b[tid];
    atomicAdd(sum, c[tid]);
}
```

Вызов:

```
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < usersNum; i++)
    {
        if (i == targetUser)
            continue;

        float* host_b = new float[productsNum];

        for (int j = i * productsNum; j < i * productsNum + productsNum; j++, k++)
        {
            host_b[k] = A[j];
            cout << host_b[k] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        //calling device to count Cosine measure
#pragma region __device__

        float* dev_c, *dev_sum, *dev_a, *dev_b, host_sum;
        float* sum = 0;

        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_sum, sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, productsNum * sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, productsNum * sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, productsNum * sizeof(float));

        cudaMemcpy(dev_sum, sum, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, host_a, productsNum * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_b, host_b, productsNum * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        scaMult_g << < 1, THREAD_SIZE >> > (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, dev_sum, productsNum);

        cudaMemcpy(&host_sum, dev_sum, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        printf("GPU <a,b>=%f \n", host_sum);
        cout << "Scalar mult between 2 vec: " << host_sum << endl << endl;

        /*cudaFree(dev_c);
        cudaFree(dev_a);
        cudaFree(dev_b);*/
        cudaFree(dev_sum);

        //free(host_b);
        //free(sum);

#pragma endregion

    }
    cout << endl;
```

Вопрос стоит в том, что именно неправильно написано, что счет происходит неверный? Нужно ли после каждой итерации и вызова ядра очищать память на ядре и на хосте и что именно нужно очищать после вызова?

В консоли результат выдает следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка как всегда оказалась весьма глупой, mybad
В общем из того, что в итоге имею:
- после вызова ядра на цпу приписал: `cudaDeviceSynchronize();`, так как есть вероятность того, что после завершения цикла на цпу и снова вызова ядра не все нити вернулись из гпу
- этого делать в данном случае не нужно, но добавил на девайсе `__syncthreads();`. Но у меня происходит атомарное сложение, посему это не нужно
- Ну и ошибка заключалась в том, что итератор `k`не обнулялся в конце цикла